# Confusion with split function in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to alphabetically sort the words from a file. However, the program sorts the lines, not the words, according to their first words. Here it is.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    lst2 = line.strip()
    words = lst2.split()
    lst.append(words)
    lst.sort()
print lst
```

Here is my input file

```
But soft what light through yonder window breaks 
It is the east and Juliet is the sun 
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon 
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

And this is what I'm hoping to get

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

Comment: Can you post some data and the expected output?

Comment: The file I am using is: 
(But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief)
and I am expecting :['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']

Comment: All you need to do is change `lst.append` to `lst.extend`

Comment: @Umer try my result. It definitely works.

Comment: @Henry I tried your result, it doesn't change the result but only sorts the words within the lines.

Comment: @Umar please see my amended result. It definitely works though, so if it isnt working for you, please let me see what source code you have with it in.

Comment: @Henry Your one works but it mentions repeated words multiple times, and I don't want that there.

Comment: @Umer So basically, it is a completely different question than the one you asked at the beginning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `words` is an array of your words from the split. When you append `words` to `lst`, you are making a list of arrays, and sorting it will only sort that list.

You want to do something like:

```
for x in words:
  lst.append(x)
lst.sort()
```

I believe

Edit: I have implemented your text file, this following code works for me:

```
inp=open('test.txt','r')
lst=list()
for line in inp:
   tokens=line.split('\n')[0].split() #This is to split away new line characters but shouldnt impact
   for x in tokens:
     lst.append(x)
lst.sort()
lst
```

Comment: That's only going to sort the lists within the list, which does nothing.

Comment: Why? lst is a list of all the words as we have appended them on individually. I've just tested it myself and I'm correct. Please understand before you downvote people.

Comment: Agreed: the basic algorithm is correct. I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's because the `for x in words` bit is a slow way to write `lst.extend(words)`.

Comment: That's not exactly clear in your answer.  I would update to add more clarity.

Comment: It's trivially obvious in my answer. `for x in words` could not be more obvious to a wombat. It even uses the same variable `words` as OP and would plug straight into his code. @KirkStrauser Fair point, did not know of the existence of extend as I typically deal with arrays. Thanks for the pointer/

Comment: @Henry it does work but the repeated words are mentioned multiple times. Could you help me with that?

Comment: You can transform it into a set. Try `myset=set(lst)`. Edit: have tested & verified this works.

Comment: @Henry Where should I do that?

Comment: After the sorting, (or before it doesnt really matter). Cheers. Effectively, a set can only contain unique elements, so its a nice way of doing de-duplication.

Comment: `myset = set(list)` followed by `print myset` should provide the desired output.

Comment: It's not working for me but it's changing the whole answer

Comment: Can you share what your full code is and what your current output is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93714/discussion-between-umer-and-henry).

Comment: Quick interjection: sets are unordered, so cast your list to a set *before* sorting it or you'll lose the value of the sorting operation.

Answer (score 7):

`lst.append(words)` append a list at the end of `lst`, it does not concatenates `lst` and `words`. You need to use `lst.extend(words)` or `lst += words`.

Also, you should not sort the list at each iteration but only at the end of your loop:

```
lst = []
for line in fh:
    lst2 = line.strip()
    words = lst2.split()
    lst.extend(words)
lst.sort()
print lst
```

If you don't want repeated word, use a `set`:

```
st = set()
for line in fh:
    lst2 = line.strip()
    words = lst2.split()
    st.update(words)
lst = list(st)
lst.sort()
print lst
```

Comment: extend doesn't change the result when I try it.

Answer (score 3):

`lst.append(words)` is adding the list as a member to the outer list. For instance:

```
lst = []
lst.append(['another','list'])
lst ## [['another','list']]
```

So you're getting a nested list. Use `.extend(...)` instead:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    lst2 = line.strip()
    words = lst2.split()
    lst.extend(words)
lst.sort()
print lst
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't have any effect on the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

`line.split()` returns a list of strings. Now you want to join those words with the list of strings you've already accumulated with the previous lines. When you call `lst.append(words)` you're just adding the list of words to your list, so you end up with a list of lists. What you probably want is `extend()` which simply adds all the elements of one list to the other.

So instead of doing `lst.append(words)`, you would want `lst.extend(words)`.